# Can Elasticsearch understand nouns, verbs etc?

Tags: elasticsearch

Hi I was wondering whether there is any analyzer in Elasticsearch to identify the grammar of the text (noun, verbs etc..)
For example when the user searches for `"fast smartphone"`, the Elasticsearch should be able to put more emphasis on the `"smartphone"` rather than the `"fast"`So I would like Elasticsearch to return results in the following order:

1) docs where both words match `"fast smartphone"`

2) docs where `smartphone` matches

3) docs where `"fast"` matches. Or maybe docs with only `fast` should never come out since the user mainly looks for `smartphones`

Comment: have you found the solution for this question?

Comment: Nope. Actually I didnt try any further since I posted the question. But I d be interested in discussing any interesting ideas.